# How to set default value in radio button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

Could you please tell me how to set the default value in radio button? I make a simple demo in which there is only one checkbox  .when it is `checked` it shows radio button I need one of them should be selected.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-torvalds-lhe9d

```
 <RFField
              component="input"
              label="hello"
              name="test"
              type={"checkbox"}
            />
```

1. steps to reproduce

   1 ) check the checkbox

   2 ) nothing is selected from radio button why  ?

expected output --> any of the radio button should be selected example **`on roll`**

any update ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `initialValues`.

```
<RFFORM
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        initialValues={{employment:'freelancer'}} // here!
        render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
```

Comment: but i need it only set when user check the `checkbox`

Comment: it is an issue because if I take submit button  and click it without `checkbox` it sends the radio button  data which is not neccessary

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `defaultValue` as "`freelancer`".

```
<RFField
  component={renderRadio}
  label="Freelancer"
  name="employment"
  defaultValue={"freelancer"}
  radioValue={"freelancer"}
/>
```

Hope this will work for you.